# How Do I Add Objects To A Specific Part of a Geometry Node Object?

Tags: particles, geometry, geometry-nodes

I followed a tutorial by GC Obaid where I created a chocolate bar utilizing geometry nodes. I'm new to geometry nodes and I'm not sure how to add, for example, fruits, nuts, etc to the back of the chocolate bar only. I'm ok with some bits being embedded and protruding out or just simply resting on top of the back of the bar. I tried a particle system, I tried modifying his node setup with more nodes, but had no idea what to add, then I tried making a separate node setup to add in the modifiers tab. I found this setup on here, but forgot who made it, sorry. The objects in question do show up with this set up, but they're far away from the bar. The bar is based off of a cube. Thank you in advance for the advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to use vertex groups (weight paint) to control where items are distributed.

While in Edit Mode, choose Weight Paint

[image: img]

Paint the area red where you want to distribute items

[image: img]

In the Vertex Group properties section, name your weights (here, "Weights")

[image: img]

Back in Geometry Nodes, drag the "Density" from Distribute Points on Faces to the Group Input. This will allow you to choose the vertex group.

[image: img]

In the Geometry Node modifier, a new input will be added. Clear out the existing text and click in it. It will show the available vertex groups (here, "Weights" at the bottom.

[image: img]

Back in Geometry Nodes, if you change the distribution to Poisson Distribution you can adjust the amount of items. I increased the max value quite a bit here.

[image: img]

Blender Guru covers this in the donut tutorial around the 20:13 timestamp  https://youtu.be/4WAxMI1QJMQ?list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&t=1213

Comment: I found that the main geometry node group for the chocolate bar will show the vertex group, not the second node tree for the toppings. I ended up transferring the nodes that are found in Guru's tutorial, now my toppings, into the original chocolate bar node tree and the objects are at the bottom, but still far away from the chocolate bar. I'm going to try to play around with the object info node's location what whatever may help. Thanks again.